# Constant value function Turing machine.

Tags: turing-machines

How would one go about writing a Turing machine which always computes to a certain value?

If the value is small, the problem is trivial of course, but how could I write a Turing machine for the function f(x) = 1000 for example?

Answer (score 2):

First clear the tape. Then have 1000 different states that each writes a `1` and then moves right and goes to the next state.